# Hadoop streaming - Number of mappers (split size)

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

We're trying to define the number of mappers using the `mapred.max.split.size` configuration on hadoop streaming.

The problem is that we don't see a correlation between `mapred.max.split.size` and the number of mappers created.

```
maxsize 356Mb => 9 mappers
maxsize 36Mb  => 50 mappers
maxsize 3.7Mb => 190 mappers
```

Anyone knows why this happens ?

The files are gzip (inconsistent sizes) and I use CombineFileInputFormat to unzip them and make the input process splittable.

Comment: In case you are using Hadoop2, use `mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.split.maxsize `.

Comment: How many files do you have, are they all a consistent size, what format are they?

Comment: @Binary Nerd I edited the question with a response to this